# Python processing multiple times

Tags: python

I'm creating a small script to automatically convert files from .jpg to .png:

```
import glob, os
import Image

basedir = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\\fimg\images\\"
prefix  = "picture"

def convert_png():
    for jpg in glob.glob(os.path.join(basedir, '*.jpg')):
        filename = f.rsplit('.')[-2]
        njpg = Image.open(basedir + '%s.jpg' % (filename))
        njpg.save(basedir + '%s.png' % (filename))

        print "CONVERTED: " + filename + '.png'

for i, f in enumerate(os.listdir(basedir), 1):
    convert_png()
```

But with this, it seems to convert the file multiple times (about 10) as it prints the converted message this amount, before moving onto the next file. Is there something wrong here that's making it do this?

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\fimg>python test.py
CONVERTED: 16094.png
CONVERTED: 16094.png
CONVERTED: 16094.png
CONVERTED: 16094.png
CONVERTED: 16094.png
CONVERTED: 16094.png
CONVERTED: 16094.png
CONVERTED: 16094.png
CONVERTED: 16094.png
CONVERTED: 16094.png
CONVERTED: 16094.png
CONVERTED: 16094.png
CONVERTED: 16094.png
CONVERTED: 16094.png
CONVERTED: 16094.png
CONVERTED: 16094.png
CONVERTED: 16094.png
CONVERTED: 16094.png
CONVERTED: 16094.png
CONVERTED: 16094.png
CONVERTED: 185500.png
CONVERTED: 185500.png
CONVERTED: 185500.png
CONVERTED: 185500.png
CONVERTED: 185500.png
CONVERTED: 185500.png
CONVERTED: 185500.png
CONVERTED: 185500.png
CONVERTED: 185500.png
CONVERTED: 185500.png
```

Comment: Consider using `os.splitext()` instead of `f.rsplit()` to grab the file extension http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html?highlight=splitext#os.path.splitext

Comment: Is `"C:\Users\User\Desktop\\fimg\images\\"` just a typo or is it in your real code? You have some backslashes that are escaped, some are not.

Comment: @nadirs `\U` and `\D` presumably aren't escape characters, so it'll work, though it's probably a bad idea to leave it like that.

Comment: @nadirs - Yes, this is the correct directory.

Comment: @Dougal is it a common behaviour in languages other than Python? If so, I'm really taken aback, since I always thought backslashes needed to be escaped always (well, except in string literals, of course)

Comment: Using "raw" strings `r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\fimg\images\"` is easier

Comment: @nadirs It varies by language somewhat. Python, Perl, and Ruby all seem to have the same behavior here; when I wrote `printf("\D")` in C (with clang) I got a compiler warning and then it printed out just `D`. In any case, it's never a good idea. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import glob, os
import Image

basedir = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\\fimg\images\\"
prefix  = "picture"

def convert_png(base):
    njpg = Image.open(basedir + '%s.jpg' % base)
    njpg.save(basedir + '%s.png' % base)
    print "CONVERTED: " + base + '.png'

for i, f in enumerate(os.listdir(basedir), 1):
    base, ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    if ext == '.jpg': # found jpg file
        convert_png(base)
```

The problem was with the nested loops: The bottom `for`, which then called `convert_png`, which itself had another loop. I eliminated the loop in `convert_png` and simplified the code somewhat by only calling that function when a file with a `.jpg` extension is found. Note the use of `splitext` to split the filename into its base and extension.